# How do you universally disable Group View in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

## How do you disable Group View in Outlook 2010 (without disabling Conversation View)?

When configuring an Outlook 2010 client, I found that unlike, say, Outlook 2019, the client did not seem to remember my view settings in that even after *disabling* the **Show In Groups** setting, after switching away from the folder and switching back, Outlook would default to showing my messages grouped by date. The checkbox for the setting remained unchecked, but the view did not reflect this, as described on a [Microsoft community Q&A](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/outlook-2010-disabling-grouping-by-date/0fd206c7-e5d1-4550-994c-90952e0c2295):

> By default, Outlook sorts the contents of my mail folders by "Date
> (Conversations)". It groups first by the date of the last message
> related to any conversation under the headings "Today" and "Yesterday"
> etc, and then within those headings the conversation groups are
> displayed.
>
> What I prefer is to sort by conversations, but not by date. So
> basically, I want to remove those "Today" and "Yesterday" headings.
>
> By right-clicking on the "Arrange By" column header, I can uncheck
> "Show in Groups" (whilst leaving "Show as Conversations" checked), and
> it acheives exactly what I want.
>
> However, everytime I navigate away from my Inbox and return to it, the
> view once again reverts to the default view where it shows e-mails by
> conversations under date headings. In order to make it the way I want
> again, I need to right-click on the "Arrange By" column again, check
> the "Show in Groups" option (it is still unchecked, even though it is
> displaying in groups), and then uncheck it manually again after
> checking it.
>
> I need to do this every single time I navigate away from the Inbox,
> and it is clearly some kind of bug because the check mark has no
> bearing on the actual display.

**How can one *actually* permanently disable grouping by date in Outlook 2010?** It works if Conversation View is disabled altogether, but I want to keep Conversation View **enabled** while keeping Group By Date **disabled**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2010 actually has a bug which prevents the **Show In Groups** toggle from taking effect. The conventional procedure to disabling viewing in groups, [such as this one](https://evadman.blogspot.com/2013/05/disable-group-view-in-all-folders-in.html), does not actually work.

That is to say, the following interface does not allow you to permanently set the setting correctly:

[image]

The proper way to do it is simple but not intuitive. It is as described as one of the answers on the [Microsoft Q&A site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/outlook-2010-disabling-grouping-by-date/0fd206c7-e5d1-4550-994c-90952e0c2295). Microsoft webpages are notorious for becoming 404s in the future, so here is the correct workaround procedure, according to user DavidBlau:

> Open the Advanced View Settings dialog ("View" ribbon => "Current
>   View" group => "View Settings" button), and make sure "Group By..." is
>   set to "Conversation" and "Sort..." is set to "Received" (or some
>   option other than "Conversation Index").  This preference sticks
>   across folder navigation.
>
> Apparently, manually setting these options is the only way to achieve
>   the desired result. Conversations need to be "grouped", which drives
>   the Group setting, and checking "Show as Conversations" does set this
>   correctly.  The problem is that the default Sort option is wrong.

In other words, the **Sort** should be changed from **Conversation Index** to **Received**. This will *still keep Conversation View enabled*. For all practical purposes, the view will look the same, since *Received* and *Conversation Index* should sort identically. However, the change makes Outlook happy and this will allow for the desired view to be persistent.

Finally, once can use `Apply Current View To Other Mail Folders` to make the change universal.